# transfer data between table views without segue?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Do I have to use segue to transfer data between table view controller?
I wrote three actions in editActionsForRowAtIndexPath method, and I expect that two of them can transfer data to another table view controller(while deleting from the original table view controller) without segue, is that even possible? Cause all the answers I see are about segue?

I'd appreciate if someone could give me a hint, I'm stuck here, just a hint is enough for me!

Thanks in advance.

My code is down below:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let moveAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Move") { (action, indexPath) in
    let moveMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Move to", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        // I need to write two handler to handle the movements
        let cancelationAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Move to Cancelation List", style: .Default, handler: moveToCancelation)
        let achievementAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Move to Achievement List", style: .Default, handler: moveToAchievement)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        moveMenu.addAction(cancelationAction)
        moveMenu.addAction(achievementAction)
        moveMenu.addAction(cancel)
        self.presentViewController(moveMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete items from data source
        self.wishList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.saveWishList()
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }

    moveAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return [moveAction, deleteAction]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A week past and I've implemented what I just wanted to.
The thing is, Yes, we need segue, and before this, I just thought I can only make segue from an actual button or something to another view, but in fact, I can make a segue from a view controller to another view controller without specifying which element activates the segue. So that is what I do,
make a segue between two view controllers and then name the segue, write handler above, then perform the segue with specific identifier.
I hope it can help any person who is new to this.

My new code is downblow:

```
    // Implementing the delete and move to function
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let moveAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Move") { (action, indexPath) in
    let moveMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Move to", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        // I need to write two handler to handle the movements
        let cancelationAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Move to Cancelation List", style: .Default, handler: {
            (action: UIAlertAction) in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MoveToCancelationList", sender: tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))
        })
        let achievementAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Move to Achievement List", style: .Default, handler: {
            (action: UIAlertAction) in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MoveToAchievementList", sender: tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))
        })
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        moveMenu.addAction(cancelationAction)
        moveMenu.addAction(achievementAction)
        moveMenu.addAction(cancel)
        self.presentViewController(moveMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete items from data source
        self.wishListBand.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.saveWishListBand()
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }

    moveAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return [moveAction, deleteAction]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers discuss this in terms of segues because it's generally easiest to use storyboards to show the interactions between scenes, and segues encapsulate those interactions. If you're doing it all in code, as your example suggests, then segues are meaningless. Instead, you can just set properties on the destination view controller manually.

Comment: You are right, maybe I'm making things more complicated. I will try to use segue then. Thank your!